# Why does the order of conditions between an `and` statement matter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create a simple function that, given a list, removes the first entry until until an odd number is indexed at `0`.

For example, the function would return the list `[4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]` as `[11, 12, 15]`.

This is the code I wrote initially:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while lst[0]%2==0 and len(lst)>0:
    lst=lst[1:]
  return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
```

If I run this code I get `IndexError: list index out of range` caused by the final print statement.

However, if I switch the conditions around the `and` statement as follows:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while len(lst)>0 and lst[0]%2==0:
    lst=lst[1:]
  return lst
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
```

I get the following correct output:

```
[11, 12, 15]
[]
```

I don't understand why the order of the conditions around the `and` statement matters. I thought that both conditions must be met to start the loop.

Comment: The right hand side expression is only evaluated if the left hand side is truthy.

Comment: In the condition `len(lst)>0 and lst[0]%2==0`, if `len(lst)>0` is false then `lst[0]%2==0` will not be evaluated, which in that case prevents an index error, since `lst[0]` would not exist.

Comment: Why not find the first index to keep (if any) and then do a single slice? No need to slice away one item at a time.